# Odoo 9 qweb float division by zero

Tags: python, report, odoo, odoo-9, qweb

How in below qweb report set condition when is discount 0 if discount not 0 work fine.

```
<td class="text-right">
       <span t-esc="l.price_unit-(l.price_unit/l.discount)"/>
</td>
```

```
            <td class="text-right">
                <span t-field="l.quantity"/>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <span t-field="l.price_unit"/>
            </td>
            <td t-if="display_discount" class="text-right" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line">
                <span t-field="l.discount"/>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <span t-esc="l.price_unit-(l.price_unit/l.discount)"/>
            </td>

        </tr>
```

If discount is 0

```
<td class="text-right">
           <span t-esc="l.price_unit"/>
</td>
```

elif

```
<td class="text-right">
      <span t-esc="l.price_unit-(l.price_unit/l.discount)"/>
</td>
```

Any simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the [official documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/qweb.html) for the qweb templating engine. There is a conditional construct there named `t-if`

In your case this should work:

```
<t t-if="l.discount == 0">
   <td class="text-right">
           <span t-esc="l.price_unit"/>
   </td>

</t>

<t t-if="l.discount != 0">

    <td class="text-right">
      <span t-esc="l.price_unit-(l.price_unit/l.discount)"/>
    </td>

</t>
```

There is no else operator yet so you will have to use two successive `if`s

**Edit:** On v10 a `t-else` operator has been created which you can use.